# Why does this flicker in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, events, svg

It works as I'd expect in Chrome and MSIE. For some reason the event is firing on the inner rect element as well as the SVG element (I think). Here's the sauce (this is the entire page):

```
<html>
<body>

    <svg width="400" height="400" style="overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid gray" id="mySVG">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" fill="red" id="myRect"></rect>
    </svg>

    <script>
        svg  = document.getElementById('mySVG');
        rect = document.getElementById('myRect');

        svg.onmousemove = function (e)
        {
            if (e.currentTarget.toString().indexOf('SVGSVGElement') >= 0) {

                var x = e.offsetX,
                    y = e.offsetY;

                if (x && y) {
                    console.log(x)
                    rect.setAttribute('x', x - 50);
                    rect.setAttribute('y', y - 50);
                }
            }
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome implement the event differently. This can be observed if you `console.log(e.target.id, x)`. Firefox logs look like this:

```
mySVG 394
myRect 35
mySVG 372
myRect 36
mySVG 354
mySVG 353
myRect 48
```

If the rectangle is not under the mouse, `offsetX` is computed relative to the `svg` element. Then, the rectangle is moved under the mouse, and one of the the next events (depending on how quick they fire) is dispatched to the `rect` element and `offsetX` is computed relative to this. Since the listener moves the rectangle relative to the `svg`, it is jumped to the upper left corner, and on the next event, it is not under the mouse any more, and the event is dispatched to `svg` again.

Chrome logs

```
mySVG 400
myRect 392
myRect 383
myRect 375
myRect 368
myRect 363
```

While the first event is dispatched to the `svg` element, all following events get dispatched to the `rect`. The reason is that `offsetX` is always computed relative to the `svg` element, whether the mouse is over the `rect` or not.

Considerung the [CSSOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-mouseevent-offsetx) definition of `offsetX`,

> return the x-coordinate of the position where the event occurred relative to the origin of the padding edge of the target node

I would say the Firefox implementation makes more sense.

The best solution to find the relative coordinates might be

```
// matrix contains offset relative to browser window
// as properties e and f
var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM();
// mouse positions relative to browser window
var x = e.clientX - ctm.e,
    y = e.clientY - ctm.f;
```

A general solution that works across SVG and HTML elements is [this internal function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/point.js) of the [d3](https://d3js.org/) library.

Comment: But the event handler is bound to the SVG element - so it fires when the mouse moves around the SVG element - so shouldn't offsetX and offsetY be the coordinates of the mouse in relation to that - like they are in Chrome and MSIE(11)?  And even though the mouse is over the rect, is it possible to get the offset in relation to the whole canvas? Is that a matter of going up thru the offsetParents and adding the X and Y coordinates?

Comment: The event handler is bound to `svg`, but events happening on `rect` bubble up to `svg`. `e.target` gives you the original element the event was dispatched to, `e.currentTarget` the element the handler is attached to.

Comment: Changed it to use offsetParent/offsetLeft and offsetTop instead: https://www.rgraph.net/tests/svg-getmousexy.html

Comment: Since the targeted elements are SVGElements, not HTMLElements, you are just geting `undefined` for those. What you are in fact returning is pageX/pageY. Just give the `svg` a margin of 100px, and the 'rect` will never be under the cursor.

Comment: Great - works a treat - thank you. FWIW I moved my option to a new page and it stopped working...:-(